# CMake error: cannot find ExtraCMakeModule

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

- [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/tree/syntax-highlight)

> TIP: On the `syntax-highlight` branch

I used `KSyntaxHighlighting` in my project. It depends on `ExtraCMakeModule`. But CMake prompts me that he cannot find `ECM`.

> TIP: My project's `KSyntaxHighlighting` in [here](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/tree/syntax-highlight/src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/)

```
CMake Error at src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ECM" with any of
  the following names:
    ECMConfig.cmake
    ecm-config.cmake
  ...
```

But I think `ECM` is executed because I saw the log above the upper log:

> TIP: `ECM` in [here](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/tree/syntax-highlight/src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/extra-cmake-modules)

```
CMake Warning (dev) at src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/extra-cmake-modules/docs/CMakeLists.txt:41 (find_package):
  FindQCollectionGenerator.cmake must either be part of this project itself,
  in this case adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH so that it points to the correct
  location inside its source tree.
```

> TIP: you can see the full logs in [CMake Error Log](https://gist.github.com/ChungZH/1ef13ee721a4b01b68f38fa1d54d304b)

The file structure is like this:

```
.
└── src
    ├── 3rdparty
    │   └── syntax-highlighting
    │       ├── extra-cmake-modules
```

---

Here is the project's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/blob/syntax-highlight/CMakeLists.txt):

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(notepanda)

list(GET VERSION_LIST 0 CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR)
list(GET VERSION_LIST 1 CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR)
list(GET VERSION_LIST 2 CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH)

add_definitions(-DVERSION_STRING="${VERSION_STRING}")
add_definitions(-DXTOSTRUCT_QT)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()

add_subdirectory(src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting)
add_subdirectory(src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/extra-cmake-modules)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Svg REQUIRED)
find_package(KF5SyntaxHighlighting)
find_package(ECM)
```

The [KSyntaxHighlighting's CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ChungZH/notepanda/blob/syntax-highlight/src/3rdparty/syntax-highlighting/CMakeLists.txt):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

add_subdirectory(extra-cmake-modules)

set(KF5_VERSION "5.70.0")
project(KSyntaxHighlighting VERSION ${KF5_VERSION})

find_package(ECM REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${ECM_MODULE_PATH})
if(POLICY CMP0063)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0063 NEW)
endif()

include(KDEInstallDirs)
include(KDEFrameworkCompilerSettings NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
include(KDECMakeSettings)
......
```

Comment: "But I think ECM is executed because I saw the log above the upper log" - Not sure what do you mean by "ECM is executed", but I see no `ECMConfig.cmake` or `ecm-config.cmake` in your following description. Also, in your log you have the **warnings** first. Why do you ignore them? Have you tried to fix them, as the warning message suggests? (That is, locate corresponding `FindXXX.cmake` file in your project and add directory, containing that file, into `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable). In error/warning messages CMake gives you direct hints how to fix the problems. Just follow these hints.

Answer (score -2):

[image: ecm]

Hey guys, I have answer now. Thanks!

Comment: please copy text as text. not as pictures.
or add thje source URL.
Just a picture is not cool, i think it is a lack of respect towards people trying to use the information.